# manual select overloaded function for rvalue or lvalue type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have overloaded methods:

```
    template<typename AnyType>
    void AnyFunc(AnyType &t);

    template<typename AnyType>
    void AnyFunc(AnyType &&t);
```

I have a caller which holds a pointer and want to use one of the functions:

```
    MyType* ptr=new MyType();
    AnyFunc(*ptr);
```

The last line runs into compile error: ambiguous overload for AnyFunc

How can I select the function I need? The simple case is to use:

```
    AnyFunc(std::move(*ptr));
```

which select the `void AnyFunc(AnyType &&t);` but this is not what I want. I need the
 `void AnyFunc(AnyType &t);` method.

Comment: What compiler? [What's the real code snippet](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you have `T&& v` (where `T` is a template parameter), you have a so-called [universal reference](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11). Not only does it bind to rvalues, but *also* to lvalues. It's a *greedy* template. It will take anything it can get and give nothing back.

Overloading when a greedy template is involved is a *bad* idea, unless you know exactly what you're doing.

With universal references, there's often no need to special-case lvalues vs rvalues. Just `std::forward<T>(v)` the parameter and the value category will be propagated.

Comment: You are right, my functions are template functions. I edit my post to make that clear. Sorry!

Comment: @Klaus: Edited. Also, what was the original reason for (trying to achieve) overloading on lvalueness vs rvalueness?

Comment: My target was to write a serializer with overloaded operator & for io to the serializing object. The syntax is the same as boost::serialize. For that I also want to use a name/value pair which should be constructed on the fly with a make_nvp function. The main reason to do this on my own way is to play with new c++11 features :-) Maybe a have not understood all the rules for this game :-)

Comment: @Klaus: My question was why you specifically wanted to overload on lvalues and rvalues, why not overload on `T const&`? Especially when serializing, there's no benefit in move-semantics, since you can't just move the object to the disk. ;)

Comment: @Klaus: As I said, a `T&&` will take anything it can get - including lvalues. And when you have two functions, whose parameter can equally well bind to an lvalue, you have an ambiguity.

Comment: You are right, the correct solution is to have a `T const&`. I saw that you have modified your answer. So I came back after understanding the "universal reference". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a fix. Your code is C++11 conforming. The Standard for these cases says that the non-universal reference taking template is "more specialized" and it will take precedence.

So your call should pick the first template. If you remove the first template, it will take the second template. It is similar to this

```
// "universal" with respect to const qualification
template<typename T>
void f(T &);

template<typename T>
void f(const T&);
```

Now this will call the second template instance because while both instances have `const int&` as parameter type, the second instance is associated with a more specialized function template.

```
const int a = 0;
f(a);
```

Same in your case. Note that it is "complete", in the sense that it works for all combination of const and lvalue/rvalue

- *const lvalue*. Both have `const U&` as parameter, but the `T&` one is more specialized, so it is taken *by partial ordering*.
- *non-const lvalue*, your case. The `T&` one has `U&` as parameter, and the `T&&` one too has `U&` as parameter, but the `T&` one is more specialized, so it is taken *by partial ordering*.
- *const rvalue*. The `T&` one has `const U&` as parameter and the `T&&` one has `const U&&` as parameter. An rvalue reference is preferred for binding an rvalue over an lvalue reference. Hence the `T&&` one is taken *by overload resolution alone*.
- *non-const rvalue*. The `T&` one has `U&` as parameter. A non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to rvalues. Hence the `T&&` one, which has type `U&&` is picked *by overload resolution alone*.

Comment: If my code is c++11 conforming, my compiler has a bug :-) I use gcc 4.7.2. Could someone check the code with other compilers for me?

Comment: @klaus i recommend to write a bugreport then. this is quite an issue.